# Running a shell script once a day at random time

Tags: bash

Need run a shell script once a day at random time. (so once every day between 00:00-23:59).

I know the `sleep` command, and the `cron` too, but

- the `cron` has not random times
- and the `sleep` solution - not very nice - my idea is launch the script every midnight and sleep random time at the start of the script.

Is here something more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best alternative to `cron` is probably `at`

- See [`at` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

Usually, `at` reads commands from standard input, but you can give a file of jobs with `-f`.

Time wise, you can specify many formats. Maybe in your case the most convenient would be

- `at -f jobs now + xxx minutes`

where your scripts gives xxx as a random value from `1` to `1440` (1440 minutes in a day), and `jobs` contains the commands you want to be executed.

Answer (score 10):

If you have the `at` command, you can combinte the `cron` and the `at`.

Run from a cron every midnight the next script:

```
#!/bin/bash
script="/tmp/script.sh"      #insert the path to your script here
min=$(( 24 * 60 ))
rmin=$(( $RANDOM % $min ))
at -f "$script" now+${rmin}min
```

The above will run the `at` command every midnight and will execute your script at random time . You should check your crontab how often is the `atrun` command started. (The `atrun` runs the commands stored with the `at`)

The main benefit in comparison with the `sleep` method: this "survives" the system reboot.

Answer (score 6):

I would simply launch you script at midnight, and `sleep` for a random time between 0 and 86400 seconds. Since my bash's `$RANDOM` returns a number between 0 and 32767:

```
sleep $(( ($RANDOM % 1440)*60 + ($RANDOM % 60) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron to launch bash script, which generates pseudorandom timestamp and gives it to unix program `at`

I see you are familiar with bash and cron enough, so `at` will be a piece of cake for you. Documentation as always "man at" or you can try wiki

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from running sed to patch your crontab as the last thing your program does and just changing the next start time. I wouldn't sleep well though.